# How to perform Post Hoc test, Tukey in agricolae package?

Tags: r, graph, anova, posthoc, tukey

I did this with

```
library(lsmeans)
```

and

```
library(multcomp)
lm(Chlorophyll ~ Treatment + Stage + Treatment:Stage, "")
```

but I'm interested how to perform a post-hoc test after TW ANOVA in R. In `agricolae` package?

```
structure( list(Treatment = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", "Nitrogen", "Salt"
    ), class = "factor"), Stage = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Green", "Pink", "Red"), class = "factor"), 
   Chlorophyll = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
   0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 
   0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1)), .Names = c("Treatment", "Stage", 
   "Chlorophyll"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L)
    )
```

After mean separation, How Can we plot the graphs for each stage with the group numbers/letters?

[image: plot]

Comment: I'm happy to show you an example on how to perform a post-hoc test; but at the moment your question is not very clear to me. (1) You're using a *linear model* `lm` but then refer to a post-hoc test following an *ANOVA analysis*. Those are two different things. Assuming you want to perform multiple ANOVA analyses (and then correct for multiple-hypothesis testing using a post-hoc test): Where is the data for that (i.e. the values and group labels)? (2) You show a boxplot but the data you give is completely unrelated. Where does this plot come from? [...]

Comment: [continued] (3) What does the `agricolae` package have to do with it? Is that where the data is from? What is the name of the dataset? (4) Where do `lsmeans` and `multcomp` come into play? What do these packages do?

Comment: Thank you Maurits Evers. Hello from .au :) Maybe I've not explained this well, I need help for mean comparison (post-hoc tests) for my group data (treatment, stage and if interaction) after running a 2 way ANOVA in R. I'm not sure how to perform Tukey HSD. After post hoc test, I want to plot BP graphs like above with denoting significance different either by letters or stars. This is just an example data. I have a big df and thinking how to perform the analysis. I'd appreciate your help with this, if possible.

Comment: Hi @Kynda. Please see my answer below; for the post-hoc test I recommend `PostHocTest` from the `DescTools` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to group data according to `Treatment`, `Stage` and the interactions `Treatment*Stage`.

1. Before performing pairwise ANOVAs, it's instructive to calculate the number of comparisons: `Treatment` and `Stage` each have 3 levels, so we have `choose(length(levels(df$Treatment)), 2) = 3` and `choose(length(levels(df$Stage)), 2)` comparisons, respectively; for the interaction term we have to consider all possibe combinations between `Treatment` and `Stage`

   ```
   combn_interact <- apply(
       expand.grid(levels(df$Treatment), levels(df$Stage)), 
       1, 
       paste, collapse = ":");
   combn_interact;
   #[1] "Control:Green"  "Nitrogen:Green" "Salt:Green"     "Control:Pink"
   #[5] "Nitrogen:Pink"  "Salt:Pink"      "Control:Red"    "Nitrogen:Red"
   #[9] "Salt:Red"
   ```

   resulting in a total of `choose(length(combn_interact), 2) = 36` comparisons. So the interaction term results in a large number of pairwise comparisons.
2. We perform multiple pairwise ANOVA analyses

   ```
   model <- aov(Chlorophyll ~ Treatment + Stage + Treatment*Stage, data = df);
   ```
3. We now perform a post-hoc test to account for multiple hypothesis testing using `PostHocTest` from the `DescTools` library. Different methods to correct p-values exist, here we use [Tukey's Honest Significant Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) test

   ```
   library(DescTools);
   PostHocTest(model, method = "hsd")

   #  Posthoc multiple comparisons of means : Tukey HSD
   #    95% family-wise confidence level
   #
   #$Treatment
   #                        diff     lwr.ci    upr.ci   pval
   #Nitrogen-Control -0.02222222 -0.1939346 0.1494902 0.9418
   #Salt-Control     -0.03333333 -0.2050457 0.1383791 0.8744
   #Salt-Nitrogen    -0.01111111 -0.1828235 0.1606013 0.9851
   #
   #$Stage
   #                  diff     lwr.ci     upr.ci   pval
   #Pink-Green -0.13333333 -0.3050457 0.03837906 0.1455
   #Red-Green  -0.15555556 -0.3272679 0.01615684 0.0797 .
   #Red-Pink   -0.02222222 -0.1939346 0.14949017 0.9418
   #
   #$`Treatment:Stage`
   #                                      diff      lwr.ci      upr.ci   pval
   #Nitrogen:Green-Control:Green  0.000000e+00 -0.40832017  0.40832017 1.0000
   #Salt:Green-Control:Green     -3.333333e-01 -0.74165350  0.07498684 0.1643
   #Control:Pink-Control:Green   -1.333333e-01 -0.54165350  0.27498684 0.9586
   #Nitrogen:Pink-Control:Green  -3.000000e-01 -0.70832017  0.10832017 0.2624
   #Salt:Pink-Control:Green      -3.000000e-01 -0.70832017  0.10832017 0.2624
   #Control:Red-Control:Green    -4.333333e-01 -0.84165350 -0.02501316 0.0327 *
   #Nitrogen:Red-Control:Green   -3.333333e-01 -0.74165350  0.07498684 0.1643
   #Salt:Red-Control:Green       -3.333333e-02 -0.44165350  0.37498684 1.0000
   #Salt:Green-Nitrogen:Green    -3.333333e-01 -0.74165350  0.07498684 0.1643
   #Control:Pink-Nitrogen:Green  -1.333333e-01 -0.54165350  0.27498684 0.9586
   #Nitrogen:Pink-Nitrogen:Green -3.000000e-01 -0.70832017  0.10832017 0.2624
   #Salt:Pink-Nitrogen:Green     -3.000000e-01 -0.70832017  0.10832017 0.2624
   #Control:Red-Nitrogen:Green   -4.333333e-01 -0.84165350 -0.02501316 0.0327 *
   #Nitrogen:Red-Nitrogen:Green  -3.333333e-01 -0.74165350  0.07498684 0.1643
   #Salt:Red-Nitrogen:Green      -3.333333e-02 -0.44165350  0.37498684 1.0000
   #Control:Pink-Salt:Green       2.000000e-01 -0.20832017  0.60832017 0.7303
   #Nitrogen:Pink-Salt:Green      3.333333e-02 -0.37498684  0.44165350 1.0000
   #Salt:Pink-Salt:Green          3.333333e-02 -0.37498684  0.44165350 1.0000
   #Control:Red-Salt:Green       -1.000000e-01 -0.50832017  0.30832017 0.9927
   #Nitrogen:Red-Salt:Green       3.885781e-16 -0.40832017  0.40832017 1.0000
   #Salt:Red-Salt:Green           3.000000e-01 -0.10832017  0.70832017 0.2624
   #Nitrogen:Pink-Control:Pink   -1.666667e-01 -0.57498684  0.24165350 0.8718
   #Salt:Pink-Control:Pink       -1.666667e-01 -0.57498684  0.24165350 0.8718
   #Control:Red-Control:Pink     -3.000000e-01 -0.70832017  0.10832017 0.2624
   #Nitrogen:Red-Control:Pink    -2.000000e-01 -0.60832017  0.20832017 0.7303
   #Salt:Red-Control:Pink         1.000000e-01 -0.30832017  0.50832017 0.9927
   #Salt:Pink-Nitrogen:Pink      -5.551115e-17 -0.40832017  0.40832017 1.0000
   #Control:Red-Nitrogen:Pink    -1.333333e-01 -0.54165350  0.27498684 0.9586
   #Nitrogen:Red-Nitrogen:Pink   -3.333333e-02 -0.44165350  0.37498684 1.0000
   #Salt:Red-Nitrogen:Pink        2.666667e-01 -0.14165350  0.67498684 0.3967
   #Control:Red-Salt:Pink        -1.333333e-01 -0.54165350  0.27498684 0.9586
   #Nitrogen:Red-Salt:Pink       -3.333333e-02 -0.44165350  0.37498684 1.0000
   #Salt:Red-Salt:Pink            2.666667e-01 -0.14165350  0.67498684 0.3967
   #Nitrogen:Red-Control:Red      1.000000e-01 -0.30832017  0.50832017 0.9927
   #Salt:Red-Control:Red          4.000000e-01 -0.00832017  0.80832017 0.0574 .
   #Salt:Red-Nitrogen:Red         3.000000e-01 -0.10832017  0.70832017 0.2624
   #
   #---
   #Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
   ```
4. Plotting distributions of values in every group requires pulling out observations for every relevant group of our 3 `Treatment`, 3 `Stage` and 36 `Treatment*Stage` comparisons. For example, for the 3 `Treatment` comparisons, you can do

   ```
   df %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = Chlorophyll)) +
       geom_boxplot() +
       geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
   ```

   [image]

   Consistent with results from the post-hoc test, there are no statistically significant changes in the mean between any of the three distributions.

   The other plots are as straightforward, and I'll leave that up to you.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- structure( list(Treatment = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", "Nitrogen", "Salt"
    ), class = "factor"), Stage = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Green", "Pink", "Red"), class = "factor"),
   Chlorophyll = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7,
   0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8,
   0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1)), .Names = c("Treatment", "Stage",
   "Chlorophyll"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L)
    )
```

Comment: You're very welcome @Kynda; I've also added a sample plot as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you Dr.  Evers, This plotting code don't work with my data frame, Why you have use pipes %>% here...  I tried with following codes and it works ggplot(df,aes(x = genotype, y = k)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)    well, I'm not interested in box plot for the moment. How can I change this to bar plots with std errs . I'm not sure at which step I have to average the results. Would appreciate your help if possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Kynda Since you're comparing means of distributions, a boxplot is a much more sensible visualisation choice than a bar plot. Concerning plotting in general, you need to take a look at some of the many available R plotting tutorials. I usually recommend `ggplot` but you can also use base R. I would suggest closing this question by setting the check mark next to the answer; if you run into issues with plotting you should ask a new question. The usual policy around SO is one question per post. That makes it a lot easier for others to find solutions and assist.